What is the mistake in the Current ripple ratio equation?
I was trying to do some research and see some online tutorials to learn designing flyback converter, I have seen this part of that play list  , I could deduce some formulas from the video but I had encountered the problem that every equation is done in terms of Duty cycle while in practice we have an Integrated circuit that control the current limit and duty ratio automatically  , I was trying to find a relation between the Ilimit and duty ratio also , Thats what i am going to ask about because I am not sure about this relation as it gives negative values for the current ripple ratio , so please if anyone help me figure the mistake it will be helpful for me :
\$ I_{peak} = I_{m(Avg)} + \frac{r}{2} I_{m(Avg)} \$ , Where \$I_{m(Avg)}\$  is average magnetizing current and \$r\$ is peak to peak current ripple , I have derived this equation from the fact that \$I_{peak} = I_{m(Avg)} +( \Delta I)\$
as in the following graph :


Now \$I_{peak} = I_{m(Avg)} (1+\frac{r}{2})\$ consequently \$I_{m(Avg) }= \frac{I_{peak}}{(1+\frac{r}{2})} \$, lets keep that in mind then we will use it later.
\$(\Delta I_{m} ) = rI_{m(Avg)} = \frac{vi}{L}DT\$ , where \$ V_i \$ is voltage applied to primary side
then \$ L= \frac{V_iDT}{rI_{m(Avg)}} \$  , then substituting  \$ Im \$ in second formula we get :
\$L= \frac{V_iD}{f}\frac{1+\frac{r}{2}}{r}\frac{1}{Ipeak}\$ , now am not sure about the validity of the last equation ... I assumed Ipeak is I limit controlled by the offline switcher but when I tried
using it it gave me negative values for r ?
I have L = 2.25mH@0.05A
I have mains 260volt and output should be 18 volt whith turns ratio 160:11
The duty cycle is 0.5017 using equation \$\frac{N1}{N2}\frac{vi}{vo}=\frac{D}{D-1}\$

When you write this: ImAvg = Ipeak/(1+(r/2)), why don't you use Latex/mathjax like this: $I_{m(avg)} = \dfrac{I_{peak}}{1+\frac{r}{2}}$ i.e. \$I_{m(avg)} = \dfrac{I_{peak}}{1+\frac{r}{2}}\$. It makes you formulas a lot less ambiguous.

@Andyaka Thanks for your advice , done formatting

OK, your very first formula ($I_{peak}$) appears to be wrong

is that part correct ? or wrong also ? Ipeak=Im(Avg)+(ΔI) , I deduced that from the graph .. what should be the correct formula with respect to thegraph ...  is Im(Avg)
